# Async not waiting for complete

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm trying to make the following method wait for complete but it stops before the line "print(user)":

```
Future<ModelUser> createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    assert(email != null);
    assert(password != null);

    var user = new ModelUser(email: email, password: password);

    final response = await post(Uri.http(_options.baseUrl, '/createAccount'),
        headers: _headers, body: jsonEncode(user.toJson()));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var user = ModelUser.fromJson(userMap);
      print(user);
      return ModelUser.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    }

    return null;
  }
```

I'm calling it from another method, using await:

```
Future<ModelUser> registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return _user(await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password));
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: does that if statement returns true?

Comment: what do you mean by stops? does it throws an error?

Comment: *Async not waiting for complete* I guess you have found a major bug in SDK.

Comment: print response.statusCode, i am sure its not giving you 200

Comment: try wrap `if(response.body.isNotEmpty){ Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);}` maybe response.body is does not contain information to convert to json

Comment: Doesn't throws a error. The code simply don't execute. And yes, the status code is 200. I've printed it on the app and in the backend. Also, i can assure that response.body contains information to convert to json.

Comment: Print the userMap after decoding and add its output as well. Post the code for ModelUser as well.